# "ones" substitution for plural uncountable nouns

Tags: pluralia-tantum

Can you please clear it out if we can replace such nouns as "trousers, scissors" with the word "ones"or should we not? Which answer is correct?

- Which jeans are you going to buy?
- the most expensive ones.
- the most expensive.
- The most expensive jeans.

Comment: All of the above are correct. The last one is redundant, however, because of course you are talking about jeans. No need for repetition.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>I would say:</strike>

<strike>- "the most expensive one" if I am going to buy just single piece of most expensive jeans</strike>

<strike>- "the most expensive ones" if I am going to buy more than one piece of the most expensive jeans</strike>

And being corrected:

"the most expensive ones" is likely the answer

And for the details please look [here](https://www.britannica.com/story/why-do-we-say-a-pair-of-pants)

Comment: Referring to jeans, "ones" must be plural. If referring to "a pair of jeans", it can be singular. As an answer to "Which jeans are you going to buy?", "The most expensive ones.'" is correct, even if only one pair is meant.

Comment: A pair of jeans as left and right, right?

Comment: "A pair of jeans", "a pair of pants", "a pair of shorts". That is how English refers to those items. It will include left and right sides, but those aren't sold independently, so there's no need to think of it that way.

Comment: thank you! What I try to clear up is ... if speaking about singular uncountable nouns like meat/ milk... we say:" Don't use that milk. Use this fresh." omitting the word "milk". Should we do the same with plurale tantum? Or should we always use "ones" instead of "jeans"?

Comment: @VencaBSpam If you're not sure about your answer, you don't have to post it; in fact, you're encouraged to do more research before posting an answer. Please do that in the future, thanks.

Comment: @userr2684291 I believe in learning through discussion, however I am sorry if I hurt your standards or this forum rules.

Comment: @VencaBSpam Well, that's not what this site is about. Regular forums might suit your needs better if you expect discussion. This site is about questions and answers. Comments are indeed used to suggest improvements to posts, but there's no point in posting an incorrect answer *with the expectation of being corrected*.